# sign while using python's ** operator and * operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, sign

```
>>> -5**4
-625
>>> -5*-5*-5*-5
625
```

There is that sign problem even if we are doing the same thing. Can anyone explain why is this happening ?

Comment: You are comparing -(5**4) and (-5)**4, I don't see a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), unary negation has lesser priority than `**` operator. That is why `5**4` is calculated first and then unary negation is applied.

So, the expression `-5**4` is evaluated as, `-(5 ** 4)`, which is `-(625)`.

Instead, evaluate `-5` first and then apply exponentiation (`**`) operator, you will get the expected result

```
>>> -5**4
-625
>>> (-5)**4
625
```

---

To see what is actually happening internally, you can split the expression into two parts. Assign `4` to a variable and use it in the expression and then disassemble the byte code

```
>>> dis(compile('a=4;-5**a', 'string', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             12 BINARY_POWER        
             13 UNARY_NEGATIVE      
             14 POP_TOP             
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

As we see here, first `5` and the value at variable `a` are used for `BINARY_POWER` operation and the `UNARY_NEGATIVE` is applied on its result.

But when you evaluate `-5` first,

```
>>> dis(compile('a=4;(-5)**a', 'string', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (-5)
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             12 BINARY_POWER        
             13 POP_TOP             
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `BINARY_POWER` operation is done on `-5` and the value at variable `a`.